# got "cannot appear in a constant-expression" when using template

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, non-type

```
template < int >  
  class CAT  
  {};  

  int main()  
  {  
     int i=10;  
     CAT<(const int)i> cat;  
     return 0; //here I got error: ‘i’ cannot appear in a constant-expression  
  }
```

even

```
   int i=10;  
   const int j=i;  
   CAT<j> cat; //this still can not work
```

but I have convert i to const int ,why compiler still report error ?
  my platform is ubuntu,gcc version 4.4.3

Thanks,

==============

Thanks all for your input, but in some cases,I need a non-const variable ,

for example:

```
  //alloperations.h   
  enum OPERATIONS  
  {  
       GETPAGE_FROM_WEBSITE1,  
       GETPAGE_FROM_WEBSITE2,  
       ....  
  };  


  template< OPERATIONS op >  
  class CHandlerPara  
  {  
       static string parameters1;         
       static string parameters2;         
       ....  
       static void resultHandler();  
  };     


  //for different operations,we need a different parameter, to achieve this  
  //we specified parameters inside CHandler, for  example  

  template<>  
  string CHandlerPara< GETPAGE_FROM_WEBSITE1 >::parameters1("&userid=?&info=?..")  

  template<>  
  string CHandlerPara< GETPAGE_FROM_WEBSITE1 >::parameters2("...")
```

other module will using this template to get corresponding parameter
and maybe specilize the resultHandler function for a special behavior

Comment: Remember: A lot of times when you get errors on one line, it is a lot of times a line above. As James' answer demonstrates.

Comment: Just because a type is const doesn't mean its value is.

Comment: I repeat: Just because a type is const doesn't mean it's value is. You could say `f(rand());`, or `int i = rand()`. Just smacking const on the type doesn't mean thing.

Comment: Where *exactly* is i going to be set? Do you expect the user to supply this at runtime? Or will it be changed at compile time? If the latter, then use a command-line construct like "g++ -Di=10" and don't define "int i" in your code. (Best to use a more descriptive and unique name than "i" in this case.)

Comment: Thanks a lot GMan,I got your idea

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A non-type template argument needs to be a compile-time constant.  Casting an `int` to a `const int` does not make it a compile-time constant.  You either need to use `10` directly:

```
CAT<10> cat;
```

or make `i` a `const int`:

```
const int i = 10;
CAT<i> cat;
```

Comment: Thanks you your input, 
but in some cases,I need a non-const variable ,
for example:

 void f(const int j)  
 {
    CAT<j> cat;   
 }

Comment: @camino: Then it can't be a template. Templates make *types*, types are compile-time constructs. If you have a more concrete example, we could help.

Comment: Hi GMan,I have add the example

Comment: @camino: It's not too concrete though. I still don't know what you're trying to *do*.

Answer (score 9):

It's important to understand what templates are: they're code that's reinstantiated for each combination of specific template types or values.

```
void f(const int j) { CAT<j> cat; }
```

This is asking `f` to create a different type of `CAT<>` each time it runs, but templates must be resolved at compile time.  Conceptually, the compiler might cope if you only ever called `f()` with values it could work out at compile time, but if you're planning to that then you can simply write:

```
template <int N>
void f() { CAT<N> cat; }
```

This *will* generate multiple `f()` functions that create custom CAT<> instantiations.

The C++ Standard doesn't even ask the compiler to tentatively accept the `void f(const int j)` version - it would just be dubious baggage hanging around waiting to fail when somebody went to use it with a value determined at run time.  People looking at the interface without looking over the entire implementation would expect `f()` to be callable with such run-time values - e.g. `f(atoi(argv[2]))`.  Or, they might put `for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) f(i)`.  If `f()` takes an `int` at run-time, and say gives it to `CAT` as a constructor argument (i.e. as a run-time parameter rather than a template parameter) then that's fine and dandy, but if the compiler had to instantiate 100,000 versions of `f()` each specialising `CAT<>`s with successive values of `i/N` the executable program size could become huge (optimisation - if enabled - may mitigate that).